# Cannot cast from Object to int in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

In my android application, at line below:

```
int add= (int) arg0.getTag();
```

getting error:

```
Cannot cast from Object to int
```

When I replace `int` to `integer` getting another error at line below:

```
sp = (Spinner) findViewById(add);
```

error is:

```
The method findViewById(int) in the type Activity is not applicable for the arguments (R.integer)
```

Kindly suggest me, hope for reply.

Thanks

Comment: it's `Integer` with a big I

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Cannot cast from Object to int

Because currently casting `getTag()` response which return Object to `int`

Use `Integer.parseInt` to parse string to Integer:

```
int add= Integer.parseInt(arg0.getTag().toString());
```

Also wrap parsing line in `try-catch` block to handle `‎NumberFormatException` if emply or invalid int string is passed using `setTag`

Answer (score 0):

To get the int value from the object you can do something like this -

```
int i = ((Integer) arg0.getTag()).intValue();
```

And in Android, you cannot use an normal integer as a parameter to  findViewById(). To get hold of a reference to the spinner in your class, that you might have defined like this -

**Layout.xml**

```
<Spinner
android:id="@+id/planets_spinner"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

In your **.java**

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.planets_spinner);
```

For more information, Checkout [Android Spinner Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this method? `findViewByTag();`

Answer (score 0):

you can update your [JDK compiler version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbXf4.png) to 1.7 or latter，also Integer.parseInt to parse string to Integer is OK.